# Why do I need to prefix all properties in my templates with model.?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

To access a model property in a template I was simply doing:

```
{{name}}
```

As explained in the [guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/handlebars-basics/)

I have now moved to ember-cli@0.1.12, with ember@canary (1.12.0-beta.1+canary.50206d0f), jquery@2.1.3, handlebars@2.0.0, and somehow I find myself forced to prefix all properties with `model.`. This happens for straight properties, like:

```
{{model.name}}
```

And bound properties, like:

```
{{view "verifiedEmail"  emailBinding="model.email" verifiedBinding="model.isEmailVerified"}}
```

Is this expected? Where is this documented? This is really a pita, because that means lots of changes in my templates.

I recall reading somewhere that object proxying was getting deprecated, but I can not find the reference to it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Routeable Components** section of [The Road to Ember 2.0](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/15) explains why these changes are necessary.

Note specifically the point:

> In both cases, the short version is that you can no longer rely on the
>   proxying behavior of ObjectController or ArrayController, but you can
>   remedy the situation by prefixing model. to the property name.

Also note that if you have a large portion of your app that would require refactoring due to these changes, the Ember core team has stated:

> We will also provide an optional plugin for Ember 2.0 apps that
>   restores existing behavior.

So you may not need to refactor immediately, if it is too much of a hassle.

Comment: Thanks, that is where I read about it. But I am a bit confused: first, these changes are supposed to be gradual and based on deprecations, not by stopping to work completely: *We plan to land support for routeable components in Ember 1.12, and deprecate routeable controllers at the same time. We plan to remove support for routeable controllers in Ember 2.0*. "Deprecate" means that, not "remove". Second, in *some* places I get a deprecation warning, but not for all. Maybe the deprecation warning does not work for partials?

Comment: And regarding your comment about not needing to refactor immediately: I **do need**, since currently it does not work. No idea when the plugin will be available. And going back to an older ember release will probably awaken other daemons ...

Comment: Since you are using the canary build, it's possible that this is an unintended regression. I think you should file an issue for ember on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is part of the transition plan to Ember 2.0 (https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/15)

> Instead of referring to model properties directly (or on this), you will refer to them as model.propName.
>   Similarly, computed properties that move to your component will need to depend on model.propName if they are migrated from an ObjectController.
>   In both cases, the short version is that you can no longer rely on the proxying behavior of ObjectController or ArrayController, but you can remedy the situation by prefixing model. to the property name.